# Criar duas linhas com Owl Carousel dentro de um foreach

Tags: php, css, owl-carousel

Tenho um loop que traz 12 imagens ou mais. 
Sendo que a apresentação dessas imagens devem seguir o seguinte layout:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Portanto, assim que o **"next"** for pressionado um novo bloco irá surgir com mais 6 itens seguindo a ordem: 7, 8, 9, 10 , 11, 12.

O grande problema que enfrento é somente na apresentação dessas duas linhas que não consigo por algum problema de lógica no meu **loop**.

```
    <div class="col-md-8">         
        <ul>
          <div id="owl-programacao" > 
            foreach ($listas $key => $itens) { ?>
                 <li><img src="$itens['src']"></li>
            <?php } ?>
          </div>    
        </ul>
    </div>

 $("#owl-programacao").owlCarousel({
    items:6,   
    navigation: true
});
```

> O resultado do script acima é somente a apresentação **de uma linha só** com 6 itens, um carrossel comum.

Comment: Ajuda awe, galera, por favor!

Comment: Não conheço este `owl-carousel`. Mas já pensou em criar uma `div` que iria conter o os 6 blocos de slider na formação que deseja, e aplicar o `.owlCarousel` neste div?

Comment: Tem problemas de semântica no seu código. `div` dentro de `ul` ?

Comment: Vou te postar uma sugestão.

Comment: usa uma api de paginação com efeito de transição, vou verificar se encontro alguma que eu usei e achei boa :) isso resolve, pois você poderá posicionar os elementos que quiser e nas quantidades que quiser dentro de containers, e isso já resolverá

Comment: ou uma solução mais fácil, coloque todas dentro de um container, (6, 6, 6 ...) e no owl-carousel, pegue o elemento pai (o container) e use slide nele

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o `array_chunk` para cortar o array em pedaços. No caso vai cortar em 2 pedaços. Então se tiver 12, será 6 em cima e 6 embaixo.

Tem que pegar o total de itens e dividir por 2, e colocar o resultado no segundo parâmetro do `array_chunk`.

```
<?php 

   # Aqui você pega o total de registros e divide por 2 para pegar metade. 
   # O resultado você coloca no segundo parâmetro do array_chunk().

   $metade = ceil(count($listas) / 2);

   # Separa ímpares de pares.

   $odd    = $even = array();
   foreach (array_chunk($listas, 2) as $chunk) {
      $even[]  = $chunk[0];

      if(!empty( $chunk[1])){
         $odd[] = $chunk[1];
      }
   }

   # Array final
   $foo = array_merge($even, $odd);

?>

<div class="col-md-8">         
    <?php foreach (array_chunk($foo, $metade) as $chunk) { ?>
      <div class="owl-carousel owl-programacao"> 
         <?php foreach ($chunk as $itens) { ?>
            <div class="item"><img src="<?=$itens['src']?>"></div>
         <?php } ?>
      </div>    
   <?php } ?>
</div>
```

### JS

```
$("#owl-programacao").owlCarousel({
    navigation: true
});
```

Comment: Entendi a sua intenção, mas separar grupos de "owl-programacao" não chega ao resultado que preciso, que é paginar em blocos de 12, massss cortar o "item", pode ser uma saída! +1

Comment: Deu certo, conforme falei acima,  mas sem sua edição não tem como colocar como solução.

Comment: Como assim paginar em blocos de 12 ? 12 cada linha ?

Comment: A ordem que você colocou ficou 
1º(na primeira linha) e o 2º(na segunda linha, abaixo do 1º), conforme a imagem da pergunta, o 1º e o 2º devem está lado a lado, entende? Pode ajudar?

Comment: Haaa entendi... tenho que pensar um pouco, mas agora não estou podendo... "/

Comment: Aguardando, meu bom. Abraço.

Comment: Marshmallow veja aí se funcionou... alterei o código.

Comment: Mano, esse `<div id="owl-programacao" class="owl-carousel">`, na posição que está, está se multiplicando, gerando um novo grupo, se essa foi a sua ideia, seguinte...Não dar certo, com base no plugin, mano. Pois só existe uma instância para cada carousel, ou seja, no seu exemplo, terei que criar uma instância para cada ID. Eu preciso somente de uma. E que os itens estejam lado a lado. Estamos quase lá, não to conseguindo.( Marshmallow  Hahahs)

Comment: Cara, chama como classe então. Tira o ID='owl-programacao' e coloca na class owl-programacao e chama como classe no plugin.

Comment: Mano, finalmente entendi o que você quis fazer, mas há um detalhe que não tenho certeza se vai impactar na minha pergunta e na sua resposta, tente me ajudar: pode haver mais de 12, quando o count chegou a 13 ele criou uma terceira instância, ou seja, uma 3 linha, é pra ficar somente 2.

Comment: Então, apenas duas... Por isso que no código eu fiz total de registros / 2 pra pegar a metade. Mas tem que colocar um ceil para arredondar. Vou alterar

Comment: Vou testar!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Uma sugestão: use o `for` nativo do php ao invés do `foreach`

```
<div class="col-md-8">         
  <div id="owl-programacao">
    <?php for($i = 0; i < count($listas); i++): ?>
      <?php if ($index % 6 == 0) echo "<div>" // abre um slide a cada 6 iterações ?>

      <img src="<?php echo $listas[$i]['src']?>" />

      <?php if ($index % 6 == 0) echo "</div>" // fecha um slide a cada 6 iterações ?>
    <?php endfor; ?>
  </div>    
</div>
```

E para o javascript, pode tirar o `items: 6` das opções.

```
 $("#owl-programacao").owlCarousel({   
    navigation: true
});
```

Comment: Por que é melhor usar o `for` do que o `foreach` ?

Comment: Eu usei o `for` porque o problema trabalha com o número de itens, logo eu preferi usar os índices do array. Não vejo sentido em usar foreach e criar uma variável pra simular um índice dentro do `foreach`, coisa que o `for` faz por padrão.